# How to click <select> element to make the options displayed in selenium webdriver C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

```
<div class="form-control">
<label class="editor-property-label">Operation</label>
<select name="root[Donut][CenterLegend][Operation]">
   <option value="Sum">Sum</option> 
   <option value="Percentage">Percentage</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I tried three methods, but all are failed.

Method1:

```
IWebElement element= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[name='root[Donut][CenterLegend][Operation]']"));
(IJavaScriptExecutor)driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

Method2:

```
IWebElement element= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[class='editor-property-label']"));

(IJavaScriptExecutor)driver.ExecuteScript("document.elementFromPoint(" + element.Location.X +10 + "," + element.Location.Y + 10 + ").click();");
```

Method3:

```
IWebElement element= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[name='root[Donut][CenterLegend][Operation]']"));

(IJavaScriptExecutor)driver.ExecuteScript("document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0],arguments[1]).click();"element.Location.X ,element.Location.Y);
```

Comment: I cannot click the <select> dropdown.so can you help me reslove the problem. and tell me the reason.Browser is Microsoft Edge.

Comment: you use `element.Click()` then if you want select by Text `new SelectElement(element).SelectByText(@"TEXT AAA")`, if you want select by Value then `new SelectElement(element).SelectByValue(@"Value AAA")` and `new SelectElement(element).SelectByIndex(integerValue)`

Comment: I don' t select any options, I onlyneed click <select> element to make all options to diaplay.

Comment: oh, so just element.Click() is enough. try it ! i done it !

Comment: `（IJavaScriptExecutor)driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.border='2.5px orange solid';", element);` I use it can locate the <select> element, but cannot click it.

Comment: i really dun know why it not working for you, but i try a test project and it working with this:
`
Browser.Navigate("http://localhost:12830/Test/HtmlView");
            IWebElement element = Browser.GetDriver().FindElement(By.CssSelector("select[name='root[Donut][CenterLegend][Operation]']"));
            element.Click();
`

Comment: In fact, the dropdown list box is out of .....,the option element cannot be highlighted.

Comment: so, upload your project on server (like googledrive) and give me the link i will try test it for you :)

Comment: Thanks~ I have resloved the question.The answer was shown as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(IJavaScriptExecutor)driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].size=arguments[0].length;", element);
```

It's work for me.....the question was settled only temporarily.
Hope better method.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the the `<select>` element via the use of `drier.findElement`, you should be able to use `element.Click()` to click on the element.

Comment: In fact,  really cannot click <select>., and  just no respond. and kill self(time out after 120s)

Comment: so the method 2 may help me , I click the position of <label> offsetby (x,y),but I'm not sure whether to wite correctly

Answer (score 0):

Name is not a css selector.
You access it like this:

```
IWebElement select = driver.FindElement(By.Name("root[Donut][CenterLegend][Operation]")
```

Comment: I use your suggestion,<select>.element still cannot be clicked.